# jQuery is not working to get input data from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to get input data from a table dynamically. It is not working properly. Could you please help me out?

Here is my code :

## Html:

```
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name/Nr.</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input value="50"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button>Click</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input value="49"/></td>
      <td>
          <button>Click</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## jQuery

```
    $("button").click(function () {
    var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();

        var asd = $.trim(tableData[0]);

        alert(asd);
});
```

Helps are highly appreciated .

Comment: js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/selimppc/FnDvL/250/. Please have a look

Comment: Welcome i posted it as answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the `input` thus change your selector. Also use `.find()`

Use

```
var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").find("td input").map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/FnDvL/252/)

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/jXQCL/)

```
var tableData = $(this).closest("tr").find("input").map(function () {
```

Instead of

```
.children("td")
```

use

```
.find("input")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the value of the input, this would be all you will need to do:

`$("button").click(function () {
    alert($(("td input"), $(this).closest("tr")).val());
});`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r6Y8/)